# SVG beams of light

Tags: html, svg

How do I make a curved beam of light with svg / html5?

It should look like this (the orange and blue lines):

[image]

Hopefully this can be done with snap.svg or d3.js

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for a cookbook-answer.

Comment: Search for svg bezier. Cubic and quadratic Bezier curves will give you lines you are looking for

Comment: @jing3142 Thanks do you know how to make it glowy and colored?

Comment: This reference should give you the basics for svg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG including the use of color within a path - glowy probably means multiple lines of different colors

Comment: @jing3142 any advice on figuring out how to get which curves I need for the 3d effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glowy/colored path can be a challange. Basically you can create a gradient stroke which is not native to SVG. However D3 has addressed this see:

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4163057

Comment: Do you think canvas might work better?

Comment: @Harry - Absolutely!! For the needed pixel control that's the only answer.

Comment: Thanks canvas is probably what I need instead. It has gradient lines which is most suitable.